# `gregorian has not been declared` error in Boost C++ 1.60

Tags: c++, boost, gregorian-calendar, boost-date-time

My source code didn't compile with `Boost C++ 1.60`

```
$ g++ -c DateTimeUtil.cpp -I../../../boost_1.60.0/include/

In file included from ../../../boost_1.60.0/include/boost/date_time/local_time_adjustor.hpp:20:0,
                 from BoostDateTime.inl:6,
                 from DateTimeUtil.h:9,
                 from DateTimeUtil.cpp:1:
../../../boost_1.60.0/include/boost/date_time/dst_rules.hpp: In static member function ‘static boost::date_time::us_dst_rules<date_type_, time_duration_type_, dst_start_offset_minutes, dst_length_minutes>::date_type boost::date_time::us_dst_rules<date_type_, time_duration_type_, dst_start_offset_minutes, dst_length_minutes>::local_dst_start_day(boost::date_time::us_dst_rules<date_type_, time_duration_type_, dst_start_offset_minutes, dst_length_minutes>::year_type)’:
../../../boost_1.60.0/include/boost/date_time/dst_rules.hpp:317:45: error: ‘gregorian’ has not been declared
           nkday ssim(nkday::second, Sunday, gregorian::Mar);
                                             ^
../../../boost_1.60.0/include/boost/date_time/dst_rules.hpp:321:30: error: ‘gregorian’ has not been declared
           fkday fsia(Sunday, gregorian::Apr);
                              ^
../../../boost_1.60.0/include/boost/date_time/dst_rules.hpp: In static member function ‘static boost::date_time::us_dst_rules<date_type_, time_duration_type_, dst_start_offset_minutes, dst_length_minutes>::date_type boost::date_time::us_dst_rules<date_type_, time_duration_type_, dst_start_offset_minutes, dst_length_minutes>::local_dst_end_day(boost::date_time::us_dst_rules<date_type_, time_duration_type_, dst_start_offset_minutes, dst_length_minutes>::year_type)’:
../../../boost_1.60.0/include/boost/date_time/dst_rules.hpp:330:30: error: ‘gregorian’ has not been declared
           fkday fsin(Sunday, gregorian::Nov);
                              ^
../../../boost_1.60.0/include/boost/date_time/dst_rules.hpp:334:30: error: ‘gregorian’ has not been declared
           lkday lsio(Sunday, gregorian::Oct);
                              ^
```

Here is what I included in my source code:

```
#include <boost/date_time/c_local_time_adjustor.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/local_time_adjustor.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
```

System info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux duong2179-ubuntu 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:07:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4) 4.8.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include this header first:

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_types.hpp>
```

Comment: why isn't this header pre-included in the `dst_rules.hpp` or elsewhere?

Comment: @duong_dajgja This and similar questions I used to ask myself every day I had to deal with boost.